# Can someone tell me how to make a server choose a ECDH_* cipher over ECDHE_*?

Tags: diffie-hellman, openssl

I am using RSA cipher for signing the certificate and  **SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback**() api to set the ECDH parameters for key-exchange. The server always ends up choosing TLS_ECDHE_RSA_* cipher suite. If i make the client send only TLS_ECDH_* cipher suites in the clientHello, the server breaks the connection stating "no shared cipher".

Can someone tell me how to make a server choose a ECDH_* cipher over ECDHE_* ?

How is it that the server decides I should choose ECDH_* cipher over ECDHE_* ciphers ?

Comment: That wiki is for using ECDH _by itself NOT in SSL/TLS_. The ciphersuites that use static-ECDH key exchange do not use a temporary aka ephemeral ECDH key and thus are unrelated to the routines that set a temporary aka ephemeral ECDH key. You need to: (1) on server use EC key with corresponding cert/chain that is trusted by client and does not have KeyUsage prohibiting keyagreement, and does not use curve and/or point formats violating client supportedcurves and supportedformats (if client is openssl this last clause is never a problem); ...

Comment: ... (2) either set only ECDHstatic ciphersuites on at least one endpoint, or _include_ them at both ends (which openssl does by default) and _prefer_ them (which openssl doesn't do by default) at the end that has preference (by default client but you can change that); (3) for TLSv1.0 and 1.1 the server EC cert must be signed by a CA using the pubkey type specified by the kx in the ciphersuite; for 1.2 this does not apply instead the CA signature must use hash _and_ pubkey type satisfying client sigalgs, see rfc5246 section 7.4.2. But as said, stackoverflow is the place for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @dave_thompson_085.

Comment: (1) Yes, i do have an EC key generated at the server side using the **SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback** api. 
(2) I tried setting only the ECDHstatic at the client side, when the server closed the connection stating "no shared cipher".
(3) I'm trying on a version TLS version 1.2.

Coming to your point of routines that set a  temporary ECDH keys, my doubt is whether **SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback** can only be used to set ECDHE_* ciphers and not ECDH_* ciphers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that this is moved where it's ontopic, and clarified enough, and the partying is over:

**Ephemeral ECDH suites:** TLS suites that use ephemeral ECDH key exchange (`ECDHE-*`) use at least nominally ephemeral ECDH keys, which OpenSSL calls 'temporary'. OpenSSL through 1.0.2 has 4-6 ways of setting these keys:

`SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh` or `SSL_set_tmp_ecdh` set (only) the 'curve' to be used; to be exact this is an `EC_GROUP` or formally 'parameter set' that consists of an actual curve defined by a curve equation on an underlying field, plus a specified base point which generates a subgroup on the curve of sufficiently high order and low cofactor, but most of the time we ignore this detail and just call it a 'curve'. OpenSSL then generates a random key on that curve for and during each handshake.

`SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh_callback` or `SSL_set_tmp_ecdh_callback` sets a function that is called during each handshake and can either set a specific key, or set a curve and OpenSSL generates a random key on that curve.

`SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto` or `SSL_set_ecdh_auto` new in 1.0.2 causes OpenSSL during each handshake to choose a curve based on the client hello, and generate a random key on that curve.

Note that each ciphersuite using ECDHE also defines the type of key with matching certificate chain the server must use to authenticate: `ECDHE-RSA` must use an RSA key&cert while `ECDHE-ECDSA` must use an ECDSA key&cert (or to be precise EC key and ECDSA cert, since the same EC key can be used for ECDSA, ECDH, ECIES, and more, but usually shouldn't). OpenSSL library can be configured with multiple key&cert pairs, one of each type, and commandline `s_server` can do two static pairs using `-cert -key -dcert -dkey` plus one for SNI `-cert2 -key2`, but other programs may or may not.

However, in 1.1.0 these functions are removed and it appears OpenSSL *always* does what was formerly `ecdh_auto`.

**Static ECDH suites:** TLS suites that use static aka fixed ECDH key exchange (`ECDH-*`) use a static ECDH key and do not use an ephemeral or temporary ECDH key. Since they do not use a temporary key, the functions involved in setting a temporary curve or key are irrelevant and have no useful effect. Instead the static ECDH key must be **in the server's configured key and certificate pair**, and the certificate must allow ECDH i.e. it must not have `keyUsage` that excludes `keyAgreement`. In addition, in TLS 1.0 and 1.1 the configured certificate must be signed by a CA using a signature algorithm matching the ciphersuite: `ECDH-ECDSA` ciphersuites must use an ECDH cert signed by an ECDSA CA, and `ECDH-RSA` ciphersuites must use an ECDH cert signed by an RSA CA; see [rfc4492 section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-5.3). For TLS 1.2 [rfc 5246 section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) and [A.7 for ECC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.7) relaxes this requirement and allows the *CA* cert to be any algorithm permitted by the client's signature_algorithms extension. However on checking I found OpenSSL doesn't implement this relaxation, so part of my earlier comment is wrong; **even for 1.2 it requires the CA signature algorithm match the ciphersuite**.

In addition for all protocol versions the key and (EE) cert must use a curve supported by the client in supported_curves extension, and the cert must express that key in 'named' form (using an OID to identify the curve rather than explicit parameters) and a point format supported by the client in supported_formats extension. With OpenSSL client this is never an issue because it supports all named curves and point formats, and in practice certificates don't use explicit curve parameters.

Thus to get static ECDH with OpenSSL:

- configure the server with an EC key (`SSL_[CTX_]use_PrivateKey*`) and matching certificate (`SSL_[CTX_]use_certificate[_chain]*`) that allows keyAgreement and is signed by a CA using RSA or ECDSA -- and like all PK-based ciphersuites also configure any chain certs needed by the client(s) to validate the cert
- configure both ends to allow (which is true by default) and at least one end to require or the preference end to prefer ciphersuite(s) using `ECDH-xyz` where `xyz` is `RSA` or `ECDSA` to match the CA signature on the server cert
- ignore `ecdh_tmp` and `ecdh_auto` entirely

... **except in 1.1.0**, which on checking I found no longer implements any static-ECDH *or* static-DH ciphersuites -- even though the static-DH suites are still in the manpage for ciphers. This is not in the CHANGES file that I can find, and I haven't had time to go through the code yet.

Comment: Pretty much understood everything you've mentioned. Yet to try it out.
However one doubt regarding the last para you mentioned: ... except in 1.1.0.
So you mean only openssl versions less than 1.1.0 only support static ECDH* ciphers. I'm using a RHEL7 box which shows the openssl version to be 1.0.1e-42. So i guess i'm safe here.

Comment: @neo: I have tested only one 1.1.0 build so far, although a usually good one (ShiningLight on Windows). I would expect any 1.0.1 to be okay on this, but check with e.g. `openssl ciphers -v kECDH`. In general remember RedHat, like Debian and others, backports security fixes to earlier versions (the `-42` part of your RPM version); I don't see any reason this _should_ be a security fix, but without looking at source I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

> ... except in 1.1.0, which on checking I found no longer implements
>   any static-ECDH or static-DH ciphersuites -- even though the static-DH
>   suites are still in the manpage for ciphers. This is not in the
>   CHANGES file that I can find, and I haven't had time to go through the
>   code yet.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/ce0c1f2bb2fd296f10a2847844205df0ed95fb8e